# Import Rxjs packages not working

Tags: angular, rxjs

After upgrading to Angular@5.x, my Rxjs imports are no longer working. For instance the below segment of code worked previously but Angular is complaining now that it cannot find Observable and interval.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';

private startMaquee() {
let index = 0;

private startMaquee() {    
  var marqueeInterval = interval(5000);
  let ndx = 1;
  marqueeInterval.subscribe(() => {
    this.marquee = this.marquees[ndx++];

    if(ndx == this.marquees.length) {
      ndx = 0;
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 6.x? That moves to RxJS 6, so you need to read https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md. Which versions of Angular and RxJS are you on, and what precisely is the error?

Comment: remove node_modules folder and try npm install again. At least `Observable` should be working I guess.

Answer (score 0):

With RxJS 6+ try the following by importing `interval` and `Observable` simply from `'rxjs'` and simply using `interval` as a method rather than instance method of `Observable`:

```
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';

const marqueeInterval: Observable<number> = interval(5000);
```

You would be importing from `rxjs` instead of `Observable/rxjs` with RxJS 6+.

Here is a simple [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdc6x8) demonstrating the functioning `interval` import in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Thanks!